# I don't know why my Python code isnt working

Tags: python

I am new to Python and don't know why this isnt working. I have searched around and seen that many people have this problem and that they can find a fix. It would help if you could explain why it doesnt work to help other people. Thanks

```
  print ("Welcome to The Haunted Theme Park...")
    print ("                                                  ")
    print ("Your aim is to not get killed and find the HOLY SWORD.")
    print ("                                          ")
    print ("Would you like to enter? 1)Enter the theme park. 2) Leave and go home.")

answer = int(input((""))

def yes():
    print ("Welcome to the Haunted theme Park.")
    print ("                                               ")
    print ("You slowly tip-toe in. In the distance you see a light.")
    print ("Do you want to 1) Walk to the light. 2) Walk another way.")

if answer == "1":
    choice = yes


elif answer == "2":
    print ("You turn around and someone is behind you.")
    print ("                                             ")
    print ("He stabs you in the throat and you slowly suffer a painful death...")
    print ("                                             ")
    print ("THE END")
```

It says there is a syntax error with def.

Comment: Paste the full error traceback.

Comment: You didn't even tell us what was happening when you run it.

Comment: erm, I said it says there is a syntax error with def

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your

```
answer = int(input((""))
```

line is missing a closing parenthesis! Or maybe is having one parenthesis too many.

Moreover, as Ciaran Liedeman adds, you have a indentation problem in your first "print" lines (why multiple indentation?).

And finally, I believe that you expect the "yes" function to be called when answer is "yes", so your code may be :

```
print ("Welcome to The Haunted Theme Park...")
print ("")
print ("Your aim is to not get killed and find the HOLY SWORD.")
print ("")
print ("Would you like to enter? 1)Enter the theme park. 2) Leave and go home.")

answer = int(input(""))

def yes():
    print ("Welcome to the Haunted theme Park.")
    print ("")
    print ("You slowly tip-toe in. In the distance you see a light.")
    print ("Do you want to 1) Walk to the light. 2) Walk another way.")

if answer == 1:
    yes()

elif answer == 2:
    print ("You turn around and someone is behind you.")
    print ("")
    print ("He stabs you in the throat and you slowly suffer a painful death...")
    print ("")
    print ("THE END")
```

Comment: That is another error, the first error is the first lines indent

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your code. Your function call is not correctly formatted, and your `input()` is missing a closing bracket after it.

Take a look at the following layout:

```
def yes(): 
    print ("Welcome to the Haunted theme Park.") 
    print (" ") 
    print ("You slowly tip-toe in. In the distance you see a light.") 
    print ("Do you want to 1) Walk to the light. 2) Walk another way.")

print ("Welcome to The Haunted Theme Park...") 
print (" ") 
print ("Your aim is to not get killed and find the HOLY SWORD.") 
print (" ") 
print ("Would you like to enter? 1)Enter the theme park. 2) Leave and go home.")

answer = int(input(""))

if answer == 1: 
    choice = yes()
elif answer == 2: 
    print ("You turn around and someone is behind you.")
    print (" ") 
    print ("He stabs you in the throat and you slowly suffer a painful death...")
    print (" ")
    print ("THE END")
```

You were also converting your input into a number, but your `if` statements were comparing it to a string value.